# Correct way to use Google Maps Javascript API infowindow on selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my project i use Google Maps Javascript API where I update a dropdown box with all markers. The goal is when the user select on of them, is to show this last one on the Map with an infowindow. Like this [Google example](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/speed_test_example.html).

My problem is when i select an item from the list then that don't show the good item on the Map and the `infowindow.setContent()` seam do doesn't work too...

What i'm doing wrong ?

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5jaq2oj1/)

**Snippet of code**:

```
$('#markerlist').on('change', function() {
  var $data = $("#markerlist option:selected").text();
  $.each(map.markers, function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $data.length; i++) {
      if (this.filter.menu.indexOf($data[i]) < 0) {
        doGeocoding(this.position, this.filter.urlSmoke);
        return;
      }
    }
  });
});

function doGeocoding(latLng, label) {  
  geocoder.geocode({'location': latLng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) { // use 2nd array item, a less-specific address
        infowindow.setContent(label);
      } else {
        infowindow.setContent('');
      }
    } else {
      infowindow.setContent('no data found');
    }
  });

  infowindow.setPosition(latLng);
  infowindow.open(map);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  There are lots of extraneous pieces of code (the map styling, why are you geocoding the address in the handler for the dropdown list?)

Comment: @geocodezip please stop putting downvote it's not really appreciate. I have cleaned the code by deleting the styling. I use geocoding in the handler of the dropdown list because is i pass the `map.makers` for infowindow then in the console i have this error message : `InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally i found a solution to manage it correctly. I hope that can help someone else who has the same problem as me.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rox05f36/1/)

```
// Handle change status from Option HTML
$('#markerlist').on('change', function() {
  // get attribute data from option selected html
  var lat       = $(this).find(':selected').data('lat');
  var lng       = $(this).find(':selected').data('lng')
  var markerIdx = $(this).find(':selected').data('marker');
  var label = map.markers[markerIdx].filter.menu;
  // get marker from map array
  var setMarker = map.markers[markerIdx];
  // set nex latlng from option selected
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

  // set new infowindows from previous datas
  infowindow.setContent(label);
  infowindow.setPosition(latlng);
  infowindow.open(map, setMarker);      
})
```